# Indexing the whole database

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, search-engine

I would like to know if it is possible to index a whole relational database without indexing all records and tables at once, and if so, how can I would be able to do this?

For example, I already have the database, but I do not want to query records manually over all tables of my database and index them all. I was thinking in implementing an event engine which every time a record is used, this is added, deleted or updated in the index until the full database is completed indexing, but this is just something I do not know how to do.

I am using nest(elasticSearch) and c#.

Comment: What is your goal that you try to accomplish with indexing whole database ?

Comment: If u already have data you can't index it without querying all table (you can perform something like index with pagination - firstly index decords 0-20, then 20-40 and so on). Let’s try to imagine that you just started project and you have no data. You want to keep elasticsearch and sql store sync. So you must handle each update. You can do that with CQRS pattern, or manually add in your repositories logic to sync with elasticsearch (to reduce overhead caused by work with elasticsearch you can create in memory queue and use rabbitmq to balance indexing between different instances of your app)

Comment: Mi goal is to have all information in the database indexed in the search Engine ready, to retrieve the information whenever I want search for objects. As far as I know i can not search for an specific object if this is not indexed, for example a Person.

Comment: Also you can create sql trigger on each update of your table.  In this trigger you will write to another table info about updated entity (table + id). But this is slow

Comment: Also elasticsearch is not just a search. It is NoSql solution and you can use it as primary store